# A pronúncia de "táxi"

Tags: pronúncia

Quando eu estava no Brasil (especificamente em Vitória, Espírito Santo), ouvi a palavra "táxi" pronunciada de duas maneiras:

- /taksi/ (como em Inglês)
- /taʃi/

Existe uma pronúncia preferida? Ou, se houver uma diferença regional, que pronúncia é preferida em quais regiões?

Comment: Nunca ouvi nenhuma pronúncia diferente do /taksi/ (regiões centro-oeste, sudeste e nordeste).

Comment: Como seria a pronúncia /taʃi/?

Comment: @MarcosSartorato Seria "táchi".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A pronúncia mais usada é:

> /taksi/

Fonte: http://www.dicio.com.br/taxi_2/

`/taʃi/` nunca ouvi, mas nunca estive no Espírito Santo. Pode ser uma forma regional de pronúncia.

Answer (score 0):

Só conheço uma pronúncia para a palavra "taxi" em português.

- Você pode verificar a **pronúncia de palavras na voz de nativos** da língua portuguesa aqui: https://forvo.com/

Answer (score -3):

Não existem duas maneiras de pronunciar 'táxi'. Deixando de lado  a possibilidade de que entre 202 milhões de pessoas possa haver algum tipo de doença que impeça a pronúncia correta o mais provável é que você tenha sido traído pelos seus próprios ouvidos ou que a pessoa estivesse a brincar (ou zoar). No Espírito Santo vivem e passeiam muitos mineiros (do estado vizinho Minas Gerais) que não raro são muito irreverentes e adoram pregar peças especialmente quando percebem se tratar de estrangeiro e ensinar ou dizer palavras erradas ou mudadas do contexto normal (aliás o brasileiro em geral é muito adepto desse costume)

Comment: Não me parece que sejam propositado. Convivo muito com novelas brasileiras, no trabalho com brasileiros e no SOpt também. Há muitas coisas que são ditas assim porque se tornaram hábito. Como "Obrigado, viu" que vem de "Obrigado, ouviu".